# Bitswap function using template metaprogramming

Tags: c++, recursion, c++14, bit, template-meta-programming

The [bit twiddling hacks](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ReverseParallel) website propose the following very efficient function to reverse bits:

```
// Bitswap: reverse the bits of the value of unsigned integral type T
template <class T>
constexpr T bitswap(T src)
{
    constexpr std::size_t char_bit = std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::digits;
    constexpr std::size_t digits = sizeof(T) * char_bit;
    std::size_t size = digits;
    T mask = ~T();        
    while ((size >>= 1) > 0) {
        mask ^= (mask << size);
        src = ((src >> size) & mask) | ((src << size) & ~mask);
    }
    return src;
}
```

- Is there any way to speed up this function by using template metaprogramming recursion to unroll the loop?
- Is there a way to make it work with extended types such as `__uint128_t`? (the original version works with `__uint128_t`)
- Does this function work theoretically to reverse the bits of types with a non-power of two number of bits if `digits` is correctly initialized to the correct number of bits? (for example a hypotherical `uint41_t`).

Comment: have you checked whether 1. a non-template one is unrolled, 2. a recursive one taking a second parameter digitsleft is unrolled (possibly w/ a helper)?

Comment: Most compilers these days know enough to unroll loops as necessary when using optimization, so I wouldn't worry about it unless it runs slower with optimization than without.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a little utility function that lets you unpack parameter packs inline into a lambda in C++14:

```
template<class=void, std::size_t...Is>
constexpr auto indexer(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
  return [](auto&& f) {
    using discard=int[];
    (void)discard{0,(void(
      f(std::integral_constant<std::size_t, Is>{})
    ),0)...};
  };
}
template<std::size_t N>
constexpr auto indexer() {
  return indexer( std::make_index_sequence<N>{} );
}
```

Next we need a compile time log function:

```
constexpr std::size_t ct_log_2( std::size_t N ) {
  return (N>1)?1+ct_log_2(N>>1):0;
}
```

we then put these together:

```
template <class T>
constexpr T bitswap(T src)
{
  constexpr std::size_t char_bit = std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::digits;
  static_assert(char_bit == 8);
  constexpr std::size_t digits = sizeof(T) * char_bit;
  T mask = ~T();        

  auto expand = indexer<ct_log_2(digits)>();
  expand([&](auto i){
    constexpr auto size = digits >> (i+1);
    mask ^= (mask << size);
    src = ((src >> size) & mask) | ((src << size) & ~mask);
  });

  return src;
}
```

Sadly this requires a C++17 feature of `constexpr` lambdas.  However the indexer work can be turned into a verbose manual implementation.

Create a constexpr size calculator:

```
template<std::size_t digits, std::size_t I>
constexpr auto size_calc = (digits >> (I+1));
```

Replace the `expand` section with:

```
  using discard=int[];
  (void)discard{0,(void((
    void( mask ^= (mask << size_calc<digits, Is>) ),
    void( src = ( (src >> size_calc<digits, Is> ) & mask ) | ((src << size_calc<digits, Is>) & ~mask) ),
    0
  )),0)...};
```

where we have manually expanded what `expand` does for us (isn't it ugly?), then have a one-argument version call:

```
  return bitswap(src, std::make_index_sequence< ct_log_2(digits) >{} );
```

with the right index sequence.

The result should be equivalent.

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/54bdYdvjM).

Some compilers resist inlining deep recursive calls.  The recursion depth here is 1 to 3 (to get the parameter pack growth).  Now a naive recursive solution is only log_2(128) or 6, so this might be overkill.

Comment: In your example x = 0xBAADF00D and r= 700f7aae; but it's not similar to function result in starter post - it's produce 0xb00fb55d - it seems your algorithm is wrong

Comment: @fsmoke Yes, it should be `auto expand = indexer<ct_log_2(digits)>();` not `-1`.  Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You can't enforce rolling out templated calls, but chances are, this will end up in one single inlined function in an optimized build:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <iomanip>

template <class T, int size = ((std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::digits
                                * sizeof(T)) >> 1)>
struct Swap
{
    static constexpr T bitswap(T src, T mask = ~T())
    {
        mask ^= (mask << size);
        src = ((src >> size) & mask) | ((src << size) & ~mask);
        return Swap<T, (size >> 1)>::bitswap(src, mask);
    }
};

template <class T>
struct Swap<T, 0>
{
    static constexpr T bitswap(T src, T mask)
    {
        return src;
    }
};

template <class T>
constexpr T bitswap(T src)
{
    return Swap<T>::bitswap(src);
}

int main() {
    std::cout << std::hex << bitswap(0x12345678l);
}
```

Comment: You could use the `using discard=int[];` trick to avoid the recursion.  Some compilers don't like inlining a 32 deep pseudo-recursive call...

Comment: @Yakk: do you mean to have `Swap<T, size, ...>` be a typedef to the next step, storing non-src-related state as template params?

Comment: [I implemented](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39357589/1774667) the `discard=int[]` version which avoids any algorithmic recursion (just some structural recursion).  However, as we are recursing `O(lg(lg(n))` times, maybe this is silly.  :)